# Tensorflow's API: seq2seq

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have been following https://github.com/kvfrans/twitch/blob/master/main.py tutorial to create and train a chatbot based on rnn using tensorflow. From what I understand, the tutorials was written on an older version of tensorflow, so some parts are outdated and give me an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    outputs, last_state = tf.nn.seq2seq.rnn_decoder(inputs, initialstate, cell, loop_function=None, scope='rnnlm')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'seq2seq'
```

I fixed some of them, but can't figure out what is the alternative to `tf.nn.seq2seq.rnn_decoder` and what should be the new module's parameters. What I currently fixed:

`tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(embedsize)` changed to
`tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(embedsize)`

`tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell,keep_prob)` changed to `tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell,keep_prob)`

`tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell] * numlayers)` changed to
`tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell] * numlayers)`

Can someone please help me figure out what `tf.nn.seq2seq.rnn_decoder` will be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/rnn_decoder) is the one you need:

```
tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.rnn_decoder
```

Comment: Is there another alternative? legacy_seq2seq is also to be deprecated according the TF website: Deprecated library for creating sequence-to-sequence models.